# How can I modify a trigger at subscribers SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I have a SQL Server 2005 publisher with SQL Server 2005 subscribers and one SQL Server 2000 subscriber running merge replication.

Is there any way to modify triggers at a subscriber with the replicating schema changes set to false (`replicate_ddl = 0`) without reinitializing the whole publication?

A solution where the triggers are only modified on the SQL Server 2005 databases is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the system stored procedure [sp_addscriptexec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174360%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to run an ad-hoc script on all the subscribers.

Comment: Thank you for you help but unfortunately this does not work in my case.  Merge-Replication is currently at SQL 2000 level and when I tried this it did not work.

Comment: @Brian: The article I linked to says it should work on SQL 2000 subscribers. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: The error I am recieving is: The schema script '0020_Script01.sql' could not be propagated to the subscriber. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147201001)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL-2147201001

Comment: Please ensure the SQL Server service account has read and write permissions on the snapshot folder and read permissions on the location where the script is stored.

Comment: The account used has permissions for everything.

Comment: The error is a permissions related error.  You need to explicitly grant the SQL Server service account permissions to the snapshot folder and read permissions to the folder where the script is stored.